# Why is the view V$_SEQUENCES empty in Oracle 12.1 but working in 11.2, 12.2, 18.3, 19.3?

Tags: oracle, sequence, oracle12c

I stumbled across a system view `V$_SEQUENCES`, which is only visible for the user `SYS`. Oracle's Doc ID 116883.1 *How to Query Next Sequence Number* shows how to make it accesible to other users:

```
CREATE VIEW v$sequences AS SELECT * FROM v$_sequences;
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM v$sequences FOR SYS.v$sequences;
GRANT SELECT ON v$sequences TO PUBLIC (or |<USER>);
```

This view is interesting, because it shows the next value to be used by a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE so.s;

SELECT sequence_name, active_flag, nextvalue, cache_size, highwater 
  FROM V$_SEQUENCES 
 WHERE sequence_name = 'S';

SEQUENCE_NAME ACTIVE_FLAG NEXTVALUE CACHE_SIZE HIGHWATER
S             N              (null)         20         1
```

If you use the sequence, it becomes `ACTIVE_FLAG=Y` and shows the `NEXTVALUE`. `HIGHWATER` seems to be the same as column `LAST_NUMBER` of the view `DBA_SEQUENCES`:

```
SELECT so.s.nextval FROM dual;
1

SELECT sequence_name, active_flag, nextvalue, cache_size, highwater 
  FROM V$_SEQUENCES 
 WHERE sequence_name = 'S';

SEQUENCE_NAME ACTIVE_FLAG NEXTVALUE CACHE_SIZE HIGHWATER
S             Y                   2         20        21
```

So far, so good, but it doesn't work in Oracle 12.1. There the view exists, has the same definition as in the other releases I have access to, but is just empty.

The view is basically defined as

```
SELECT inst_id                                 AS inst_id, 
       KGLNAOWN                                AS sequence_owner,
       KGLNAOBJ                                AS sequence_name,
       KGLOBT08                                AS object#,
       decode(bitand(KGLOBT00,1),0,'N','Y')    AS active_flag,
       decode(bitand(KGLOBT00,2),0,'N','Y')    AS replenish_flag,
       decode(bitand(KGLOBT00,16),0,'N','Y')   AS wrap_flag,
       KGLOBTN0                                AS nextvalue,
       KGLOBTN2                                AS min_value,
       KGLOBTN3                                AS max_value,
       KGLOBTN1                                AS increment_by,
       decode(bitand(KGLOBT09,1),0,'N','Y')    AS cycle_flag,
       decode(bitand(KGLOBT09,2),0,'N','Y')    AS order_flag,
       KGLOBTN4                                AS cache_size,
       KGLOBTN5                                AS highwater,
       decode(KGLOBT10,1,'Y','N')              AS background_instance_lock,
       decode(KGLOBT10,1,KGLOBT02,null)        AS instance_lock_flags
  FROM X$KGLOB 
 WHERE KGLOBTYP = 6 
   AND KGLOBT11 = 1;
```

In Oracle 12.1, I found a row in X$KGLOB with the right sequence_owner and name, it even has the right KGLOBTYP = 6, but KGLOBT11 = 0, which would explain why the view does not show the row. However, this KGLOBT11 = 0 doesn't have any column that shows the nextvalue of the sequence.

What is going on???

Comment: Looking at `v$_sequences` could be problematic, and looking at `X$K` tables even more so.   You likely know about the cache of sequences; I would imagine that cache could be sensitive to CDB/PDB, RAC and non-RAC, etc.

Comment: Via [comments on this article](https://chandlerdba.com/2015/03/17/sequences-where-did-the-view-go/), this may be bug 20108098. There seems to be a patch, but no details.